# Local Repository Server not working

Tags: server, repository

My name is Aviel and for a long time I've tried to configure a local repository server in my organization.
My server is a VM Machine compatible with ESXi 6.0 environment and higher. OS: Ubuntu 20.04 I worked step by step according to the tutorial in [this link](https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-local-apt-repository-server-ubuntu/).
I didn't get any special errors during the process.

My client test is a physical PC running Ubuntu 20.04. when I try to execute `sudo apt update`, I get an error (attached screenshot).

I tried many solutions and just before posting this I saw the suggestion in [this link](https://github.com/Stifler6996/apt-mirror/commit/c6a8a7eacf48f72453f1d5920a1514761679c952), so I added this line to the apt-mirror file, but it doesn't work yet.

Client error:

[image: client error]

Comment: If the screen shot is of text it belongs in the question not as a picture.

Comment: The `404 Not Found` error suggests that either the IP address of the mirror is not what you expect it to be, or that Apache is not running on the mirror.

Comment: @user535733 , if I go to the client and and open Mozilla browser I reach the Apache.